# Sumar elementos de una matriz y guardarlos en array

Tags: java

Hola amigos como puedo sumar los elementos de n filas de una matriz y almacenarlos en un array, por ejemplo sumo los elementos de las filas pares de la matriz y las voy almacenando en un array.

Necesito que en cada posición me guarde la suma de cada fila que sume de la matriz.

Yo se sumar los elementos lo que no se es como almacenarlos en un arreglo.

Este es mi código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            sumafilas=0;

            for (int j = 0; j <columnas; j++) {
                if (i%2==0){
                sumafilas+=matriz[i][j];

            }

  }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el código que llevas hasta el momento?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matriz[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            sumafilas=0;
            
            for (int j = 0; j <columnas; j++) {
                if (i%2==0){
                sumafilas+=matriz[i][j];
                
            }
           
            }

Comment: @DamianAndreu Pulsa en [edit] y añade el código ahí, en un comentario no es muy útil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si únicamente deseas insertar los resultados que fueron sumados, debes definir un array de acuerdo al numero de tus filas, si el número de filas es impar, definelo así:

```
   int[] resultados = new int[filas/2+1];
```

si el número de filas es par lo definirías de esta forma:

```
   int[] resultados = new int[filas/2];
```

esto es importante debido a que si el numero de filas es impar, por ejemplo 5 y usas filas/2 tendrás como resultado 2 y solo permitiría 2 elementos en el array que almacena los resultados, pero en este caso necesitarías 3.

---

Ahora para almacenar los valores realizarlo de esta forma:

```
int contador = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
    sumafilas = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {                      
            sumafilas += matriz[i][j];                                                       
        }
    }    

     if(sumafilas != 0){ //Solo almacena valores sumados (pares).
            //Agrega valor a array resultados.
            resultados[contador] = sumafilas;
            //incrementa el indice en el array para insertar el siguiente elemento.
            contador++;
      }            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que los elementos que almacenas en la matriz son enteros, y habiendo modificado algunas cosas de tu código tendrás que medificar tu código de la siguiente manera:

**Primero**, has de crear un array donde almacenas la suma de los elementos de las filas pares.

```
int[] sumaElementosFilas = new int[matriz.length / 2];
```

Después, tienes que hacer dos cosas fundamentales. La primera es crear un contador, el cual servirá para almacenar los datos en una posición del array de forma lineal.

La **segunda** es:

`sumaElementosFilas[contador] = sumafilas;`

Aquí lo que hago es guardar el sumatorio de todas las columnas de la matriz en una misma fila en una posición del array. Una vez se guarda, sale del bucle y aumenta en una unidad el contador.

La comprobación de la paridad de las filas,  podrías hacerla antes del segundo bucle. Según como lo tienes, lo que haces es estar comprobando la paridad de la fila en cada entrada de la matriz, en vez de en cada fila, lo cual es un coste que te puedes ahorrar.

Todo esto quedaría así:

```
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
            sumafilas = 0;
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                    sumafilas += matriz[i][j];
                    sumaElementosFilas[contador] = sumafilas;
                }
                contador++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo me a sido de mucha ayuda, soy cubano y no tenia internet hasta hoy por eso me demore en agradecerle.